# Delete rows from DF with partial string matching

Tags: pandas, python-3.6

From the following df I want to delete all rows with do not start with CBT_21 or CBT_TY1:

```
               code        date type  strike  settlement
0    CBT_06_F2016_S  2015-01-02    P   240.0        2.45
1    CBT_06_F2016_S  2015-01-02    P   360.0       48.60
2    CBT_21_F2016_S  2015-01-02    P   210.0        0.80
3    CBT_TY1_F2016_S 2015-01-02    P   320.0       23.20
4    CBT_06_F2016_S  2015-01-02    C   430.0        3.70
```

desired output:

```
               code        date type  strike  settlement
0    CBT_21_F2016_S  2015-01-02    P   210.0        0.80
1    CBT_TY1_F2016_S 2015-01-02    P   320.0       23.20
```

What is the most efficient pythonic way of doing this please? I have a very large file to process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with [`startswith`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.startswith.html) and chain by `|` (bitwise `or`) or use [`str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) with `^` for select starts of strings:

```
m = df['code'].str.startswith('CBT_21') | df['code'].str.startswith('CBT_TY1')
df = df[m]
print (df)
              code        date type  strike  settlement
2   CBT_21_F2016_S  2015-01-02    P   210.0         0.8
3  CBT_TY1_F2016_S  2015-01-02    P   320.0        23.2
```

Another solution:

```
m = df['code'].str.contains('^CBT_21|^CBT_TY1')
df = df[m]
print (df)
              code        date type  strike  settlement
2   CBT_21_F2016_S  2015-01-02    P   210.0         0.8
3  CBT_TY1_F2016_S  2015-01-02    P   320.0        23.2
```